What is the behavior of Azure Logic App "Until" Connector
I'm Using Logic app Until connector and Condition connector. Condition connector kept inside Until Connector (Nested).

Question:
Scenario-1:
If any of the connectors under "Condition" failed before the last iteration and if the last iteration of the loop "Success"/ "Skipped" then the whole while loop marked as "Success". Even though it has the failed iterations previously. Finally the logic app run also marked as "Success".
The Run ID: "08584753603580670935562390888CU11" has failed iterations on 2 & 4. Success iterations are 1, 3, 5
Run history:


Scenario-2:
If connectors under "Condition" failed in the last iteration, the whole while loop marked as "Failed". Even though if all the previous iterations are "Success". Finally the logic app run also marked as "Failed".
The Run ID: "08584753596646149685616977734CU12" has success iterations on 1, 2, 3 & 4. Failed iteration is 5
Run history:


From the above tests, I assume only "Until" loops marked as failed when the last iteration status is "Failed".
Can anyone explain the behavior of Until Loop connector and its fair use/best practices.....

To overcome this inconvenience, you can use a Scope inside your Until action, and when the scope fails, manage the error using the "run after" behaviour.
For example, this Logic App run hasn't failed despite the error in the last iteration:

As you can see, the "Compose 1" action serves as an error handler - it's been set up to run only when the "Scope" fails, and it prevents the "Until" action from failing.
You can use a similar approach, only instead of using "Compose 1" you can e.g. log an error or use any other action you deem necessary.
If you need the workflow to fail when any action inside the "Until" action fails in an earlier iteration, you can use the Terminate action.
